# Writing custom optimizers questions

Tags: tensorflow

apologies beforehand if these are basic questions - I've done some digging around and can't find straightforward answers. If there are links to any resources that can help that would be great too!

I'm currently looking at the below piece of code for a class that implements optimizer.optimizer. I'm having trouble understanding the following things:

```
def _create_slots(self, var_list):
    # Create slots for the first and second moments.
    for v in var_list:
        self._zeros_slot(v, "m", self._name)

def _apply_dense(self, grad, var):
    lr_t = math_ops.cast(self._lr_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    beta_t = math_ops.cast(self._beta_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    alpha_t = math_ops.cast(self._alpha_t, var.dtype.base_dtype)
    eps = 1e-7 #cap for moving average

    m = self.get_slot(var, "m")
    m_t = m.assign(tf.maximum(beta_t * m + eps, tf.abs(grad)))

    var_update = state_ops.assign_sub(var, lr_t*grad*(1.0+alpha_t*tf.sign(grad)*tf.sign(m_t) ) )
    #Create an op that groups multiple operations
    #When this op finishes, all ops in input have finished
    return control_flow_ops.group(*[var_update, m_t])
```

1. In create slots, is it allocating a variable "m" for each weight? And if I needed more variables then would I have another line in the for loop like self._zero_slots(v, "another variable", self._name) and so forth?
2. Is the input grad and var in _apply_dense the gradient per weight and variables per weight? What if I needed other gradients, e.g. if I wanted to do a global update based on the whole gradient matrix?
3. How is m being updated with new weights? It seems like on every iteration it would just be multiplied by beta.
4. In the line with var_update, it seems like var is being updated with the weight update, but I can also get my variables from var?